# How should I break down a huge table of contents?

Tags: style, book

I am creating a table of contents for a book, and there are 4 ways of splitting information up. The biggest zones are 'Chapters', those can span several pages; these are bold, underlined and in large font.

Secondly are 'Modules', these are in bold and are color coded, and break only larger chapters up; else, they're not used.

Thirdly there are 'Sections', these are what group tasks together and either split up chapters or modules (if used); these are underlined.

And lastly there are 'Tasks' themselves, these sometimes don't exist if the section is fairly straight forward; they have no formatting.

Example: A chapter could be 'Windows Setup'. Modules could be 'Textmode', 'graphical', and 'OOBE'. Sections could be 'New Installation' and 'Repair/Upgrade'. Tasks could be 'format the drive', 'set the date & time' and 'choose a password'.

- Question 1. Is this a good way to lay everything out?
- Question 2. Does anybody know of a word to use instead of 'tasks/task'?

Answer (score 2):

Many of the technical books I read have two tables of contents: a short, broad list, and a detailed list. I find this format useful.

Synonyms for 'task' include 'job', 'project' and 'labour'. However, for technicial books repeating words can be helpful for the reader.

Comment: hmm I got told not to repeat parts of the book as 'nobody wants that'

Comment: I'm not suggesting repeating parts of the book. Instead I'm saying consistent wording can be helpful. So, for example, every chapter may have a section titled 'Project for you to try'.

Comment: I use words like choose, select, enable/disable show/hide add/remove, make, allow/disallow for the names of tasks, as well as jargon names

Comment: If having two Tables of Contents isn't an option, you can also have a general, simplified TOC and a more detailed one at the beginning of each section.